# Merging two columns into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

If I have one dataframe (df) with:

```
Columnx      Columny
1             NA
2             NA
3             NA
NA            4
NA            5
NA            6
```

and want

```
Column z
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I do this in the simplest way possible? Essentially x and y are date columns, but due to a previous merge I have two date columns each filled with NA where the other is occupied, but only want one date column.

Comment: I think the dupe is more about fillna keeping 2 columns. This is to collapse into 1 @BEN_YO

Comment: Not sure if the dupe is correct here.

Comment: @yatu I still think this is dup for fillna ...

Comment: Actually you're right @ben `df.Columnx.fillna(df.Columny)` is enough, my bad

Comment: Missunderstood what the dupe does @BEN_YO

Answer (score 4):

Use `df.combine_first()`:

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]: 
   Column x  Column y
0       1.0       NaN
1       2.0       NaN
2       3.0       NaN
3       NaN       4.0
4       NaN       5.0
5       NaN       6.0

In [59]: df['Column x'].combine_first(df['Column y'])
Out[59]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    6.0
Name: Column_x, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) here:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.stack().to_numpy(), columns=['Columnsz'])

   Columnsz
0       1.0
1       2.0
2       3.0
3       4.0
4       5.0
5       6.0
```